# Ubuntu 10.04 live cd keyboard problem

Tags: drivers, keyboard, ubuntu-10.04, livecd

Today I downloaded the Ubuntu 10.04 x64 .iso but when trying it out in live cd the keyboard of both my laptop and a microsoft branded one didn't work. I was planning into installing Ubuntu in a partition but I couldn't even put my info in the installation process to do it.

Is this a problem with the .iso or the driver? because I'm afraid that if I can actually go ahead with the installation then the keyboard won't work after that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if it's going to work, but did you try to test Ubuntu 32 bits version? [It's suggested](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=765428) to do it if:

> 3) You have hardware / peripherals
>   that are not yet supported for some
>   odd reason under 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers. I've had similar troubles with the keyboard and mouse since 9.04, nothing has worked yet. It'll persist after you install most likely :(